# Is there any Report with similar functionality as Extent report for python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, report

I am new to python.So need some help regarding the Reporting features in python.Is there any report with the same functionality as Extent Report for java.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 10):

[Allure2](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2) it is a good option to me.

[image]